# Disable syntax-highlighting on specific file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am using **Visual Studio Code** to make annotations with javascript/json-like sentences and english words.

I selected on `Select Language Mode` the value `Javascript`.

Now, I want to disable all the syntax-highlighting on that file.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using JavaScript instead of JSON? I noticed switching to JSON removes syntax highlighting. There are other options as well if this doesn't do it for you.

Answer (score 7):

Open your file in vscode. Then, in the status bar at the bottom of the window you'll see the language-highlighting mode (e.g. JavaScript) approx 3 icons from the right-hand side of the bar. Click on it and change the mode to "Ignore" for no syntax highlighting.

If you don't see the status bar, turn it on via: View > Appearance > Show Status Bar.

Comment: For VSCode v1.55 it's called `Plain Text`

Comment: Looks like this is a one-time effect. How do I make it remember the setting the next time I close and open the file again?