# How can I disable syntax coloring on files with no extension (file type) in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make notes files with either file type extension `.txt` or no extension (like `notes.txt` vs `notes`), but VS Code is insisting on syntax coloring, and I'm not seeing an option to disable it or even modify the settings.

[image]

The syntax coloring makes no sense to me anyway when I'm just writing English sentences, so it's just gumming up my usage. I can't even tell what language it's trying to check against. JSON coloring pasted into the file looks nice, but otherwise it's completely random to me.

Comment: It's not random. Quotation marks indicate the beginning and ending of strings and other entities. Doesn't really matter which language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable syntax coloring in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712370/how-to-disable-syntax-coloring-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Or this? [Disable syntax-highlighting on specific file in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768252/disable-syntax-highlighting-on-specific-file-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: **Or this?** [Disable syntax highlighting for text files (*.txt) in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64543361/disable-syntax-highlighting-for-text-files-txt-in-vscode)